# One shot getCurrentLocation cannot get a new location when mobile data is turned off in Titanium Android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, titanium, titanium-mobile

i'm creating simple application to get current device's location when a button pressed. here's my code :

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    layout:'vertical'
});

var btnGetLocation = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:'Get Location (Once)',
    width:'100dp'
});

btnGetLocation.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    getDeviceLocation();
});

function getDeviceLocation(){
    var longitude = 0.0;
    var latitude = 0.0;
    var altitude = 0;
    var heading = 0;
    var accuracy = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    var timestamp = '';
    var altitudeAccuracy = 0;

    var address = '';

    var errMessage = '';

    if (Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled === false){
        errMessage = 'Geolocation access turned off';
    }
    else{
        Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
        Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;

        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
            if (!e.success || e.error){
                errMessage = 'error: ' + JSON.stringify(e.error);
                return;
            }

            if (typeof e.coords.longitude !== 'undefined' && e.coords.longitude !== null){longitude = e.coords.longitude;}
            if (typeof e.coords.latitude !== 'undefined' && e.coords.latitude !== null){latitude = e.coords.latitude;}
            if (typeof e.coords.altitude !== 'undefined' && e.coords.altitude !== null){altitude = e.coords.altitude;}
            if (typeof e.coords.heading !== 'undefined' && e.coords.heading !== null){heading = e.coords.heading;}
            if (typeof e.coords.accuracy !== 'undefined' && e.coords.accuracy !== null){accuracy = e.coords.accuracy;}
            if (typeof e.coords.speed !== 'undefined' && e.coords.speed !== null){speed = e.coords.speed;}
            if (typeof e.coords.timestamp !== 'undefined' && e.coords.timestamp !== null){timestamp = e.coords.timestamp;}
            if (typeof e.coords.altitudeAccuracy !== 'undefined' && e.coords.altitudeAccuracy !== null){altitudeAccuracy = e.coords.altitudeAccuracy;}
        });

        // reverse geocoding
        Titanium.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder(latitude,longitude,function(e){
            if (e.success) {
                var places = e.places;
                if (places && places.length) {
                    address = places[0].address;
                } else {
                    address = "No address found";
                }
            }
            else {
                address = e.error;
            }

            alert('Longitude = ' + longitude + '\nLatitude = ' + latitude + '\nAltitude = ' + altitude + '\nHeading = ' + heading + '\nAccuracy = ' + accuracy + '\nSpeed = ' + speed + '\nTimestamp = ' + new Date(timestamp) + '\nAltitude Accuracy = ' + altitudeAccuracy + '\nAddress = ' + address + '\nError Message = ' + errMessage);
        });
    }
}

win.add(btnGetLocation);

win.open();
```

The condition is : device don't have any internet connection (data connection) and only GPS is turned on. when i press the button (get location in one shot), i can't get a new location.. the device still show my old location with old timestamp too and never get a new location even my current location is changed.. does anyone know how to get current location (one shot) only with GPS connection? many thanks..

Comment: May be your code is right. Please try it after a long distance. e.g. 2 to 3 kilometer difference. then you can get exactly result.

Comment: @MRT Hi, i've tried to move from my first location to other location.. but it still show my old location.. do u have other suggestion? thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use getCurrentPosition under Android this is not a Titanium bug.
If you read the documentation:

*Retrieves the last known location from the device.

On Android, the radios are not turned on to update the location, and a cached location is used.

On iOS the radios may be used if the location is too "old".*

That means that getCurrentPosition (under Android) return the last position that has been cached by the system until an application (that uses location services) requires a new location (like google maps).
So... what you can do is not to use getCurrentPosition when the application starts... but use an event called "location" that fires everytime a new location si available.

Luca

Comment: icic.. that's helps me a lot since i don't know that.. thanks dude.. you are awesome.. :)

Comment: If you are under Android the best thing that you could do is a well-done management of the geolocation event.
That's what I do since there's no way to force the refresh of the current position.

Comment: You have to create a function that will manage this event Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', yourFunction); that fires when the OS refreshes the current position .
(sorry for the double comment)